# Laravel: I come back from .dev in my localhost to localhost/site/public but can't login

Tags: laravel

Everything worked fine on my local app when .dev domain worked. Now I can't open my app on neither browser (chrome, firefox, opera) so I decided to return to localhost/sitename/public...

I restarted apache on xampp after delete config for .dev and login page apper successfully, but when I enter username and password instead of home page it stays on http://localhost/sitename/public/login and shows me button when says Toggle Navigation in simple html and then site name. When I click on site name it redirects me to http://localhost/home and there says:

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the
>   referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author
>   of that page about the error.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>   Error 404 localhost Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/7.1.4

What's this about?

Comment: Rather add the error message here.

Comment: Have you check your .env ? APP_URL= http://localhost

Comment: I add wrror message in question. In .env is APP_URL=http://localhost

Comment: Replace your `.dev` domain with a new one - `.test` is available for this. Otherwise, you're going to have to set up pretty URL handling in your webserver for `sitename/public`.

Comment: I tried .example and it's working fine, user can login and redirect me to home page. But, how to set to sitename/public?